# what is the correct path to the iMovie Projects folder to use in an AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm working on a simple AppleScript to make a copy of an iMovie project file.  I have added this property to the script:

```
property iMovieProjects : alias (home directory of (system info) as string) & "Movies:iMovie Projects"
```

This gives me the error

> File alias Macintosh HD:Users:my user name:Movies:iMovie Projects of  wasn't found

What's the correct path?  I tried iMovie Project.localized but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, looks like you need to use the Finder. Also i added a little simplification on getting the home path.

```
property iMovieProjects : ""

tell application "Finder" to set iMovieProjects to alias ((home as string) & "Movies:iMovie Projects")
```

**EDIT**:  *Heres a one line solution that does not use the Finder, based on ideas from mklement0 & regulus6633*

```
property iMovieProjects : alias ((path to movies folder as text) & "iMovie Projects.localized")
```

It appears this folder is some kind of special bundle type folder and thats why we were needing the finder to parse it correctly. Using its full .localized name resolves it.

Comment: While your solution works, it is not necessary to involve Finder - simply applying the same way you parenthesize here to the OP's code - making sure that the path string is built in its entirety before passing it to `alias` - makes it work - see my answer.

Comment: Hi, i'd agree completely, but can't get your answer to work, it throws a "File alias ... wasn't found" error. I'm still on 10.7, so could be something in that.

Comment: That's bizarre - I wouldn't expect to act 10.7 differently; even @regulus6633, who's  on 10.9, as I am, had the same problem. What if you prefix my command with `tell AppleScript to`? What if you just use `(path to movies folder as text)` as the `alias` argument? Is the behavior different if you run with `osascript`? I wouldn't expect localization issues to play a role here either.

Comment: This works: `set iMovieProjects to alias (path to movies folder as text)` It's an odd one, are you using ScriptEditor or something else?

Comment: I'm using the regular AppleScript Editor. If you look in the "Replies" tab when the error occurs, what do you see? What do you see with the example that does work? Does the text representation of the path end in `:`? How about `set iMovieProjects to alias ((path to home folder as text) & "Movies")`?

Comment: Think i found it. See update to my answer. Does not explain why your system works though, possibly as i'm in Australia and regulus6633 Denmark, it is a localisation issue, your US system does not use .localized?

Comment: Now it makes sense - thanks. Yes, it is `"iMovie Projects.localized"` on my US system too (which makes sense) - the problem was that I had created the folder _manually_ before - as only `"iMovie Projects"` - instead of using the one that iMovie creates.

Comment: Good catch about the ".localized" name on the folder. That's clears up the alias error mystery.

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***: As adamh discovered, the reason for the alias error is because the real name of the folder is "iMovie Projects.localized". Get info on the folder and you will see it.

I would add that an easier method to get to a folder is using the "path to" command. Using that you can get to virtually every known folder. In your case we can get directly to the Movies folder. You can look in the applescript dictionary of the standard additions to see all of the folders it knows. As such I would reference that folder as follows.

```
set iMovieProjects to alias ((path to movies folder as text) & "iMovie Projects.localized:")
```

Finally you'll notice that I did not use a property for iMovieProjects. That's because when you compile a script a property will hard-code the path into the script... meaning that the script will only work for this particular user. If the script is used by another user it will still point to the Movies folder of the person at compile time. Thus we don't use a property and the script will work for any user.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for the helpful info on `path to`, but it doesn't address the OP's problem per se, which stems from how things are (not) parenthesized - see my answer.

Comment: Yes, I was rewriting my answer when you posted because I noticed "alias" was not working as expected.

Comment: A hypothetical add'l +1 for pointing out the property-initialization issue - note, though, that it doesn't preclude the use of properties per se.

Comment: There is NO need to involve Finder to create the alias (also, the class of the instance returned by Finder is different from the globally available `alias` class) - as long as the argument given to the global `alias` is an HFS-style path representing an _existing_ file, it should work; e.g., `set a to alias ((path to home folder) as text)` - note the parentheses.

Comment: I know about the iMovie Projects.localized.  I tried using that as the folder name with the same error.  I'll try the `path to movie folder as text`.  As for the property, this script is only to be used by me on my MacBook.  I don't care about other users.

Answer (score 0):

**Update2** (thanks, @adamh): Even though the iMovie projects folder name appears as `"iMovie Projects"` in Finder in English-language locales, the actual - locale-independent - name is `"iMovie Projects.localized"`. (If you want to refer to the folder by its *localized* name, prefix the `set` command with `tell application "Finder"`, as in @adamh's answer's first snippet.)

---

You simply need to change how you parenthesize - the string to pass to `alias` must be built in its entirety inside parentheses:

```
property iMovieProjects : ""
set iMovieProjects to alias ( ¬
 (home directory of (system info) as string) & "Movies:iMovie Projects.localized" ¬
 )
```

**Update1**: @regulus6633 makes the excellent point that you shouldn't *initialize* a property with a specific user's path, as it will get compiled into the script. Thus, the above snippet initializes the property to an empty string and then assigns a value dynamically - which will then reflect the *current* user's path - in a separate `set ... to` statement.

Your original statement inadvertently creates a *list with 2 elements*, whose first element is a an alias of your home directory and whose second element is the string "Movies:iMovie Projects".

---

Simplified version with the `path to` command demonstrated in @regulus6633's answer (the same need to parenthesize applies):

```
property iMovieProjects : ""
set iMovieProjects to alias ( ¬
    (path to movies folder as text) & "iMovie Projects.localized" ¬
  )
```

Comment: Your explanation is not working for the path in my example. I get the error with "set iMovieProjects to alias ((path to movies folder as text) & "iMovie Projects:")".

Comment: Plus I get the error with the 2 examples you give here.

Comment: Sorry to keep writing but I'm using 10.9. It might be the reason it works for you and not for me.

Comment: @regulus6633: Interesting. Works perfectly fine here on OS X 10.9.2 - what are you running? Please note that the "iMovie Projects" folder must _exist_.

Comment: I'm on 10.9.2 too and that folder does exist. I can reveal it as I show in my example code.

Comment: @regulus6633: I have no explanation; see if this works: `tell me to set iMovieProjects to alias ("Macintosh HD:Users:" & short user name of (system info))`. To then see my point about parentheses, run `tell me to set iMovieProjects to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:" & short user name of (system info)`

Comment: @regulus6633: Thanks to adamh we have the answer - see my update.